# node cannot be made up in private blockchain by using command line

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain

I have created the genesis.json 
The genesis json content is

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 46860,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "constantinopleBlock": 5,
    "clique": {
      "period": 5,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5c596a29",
  "extraData": "",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0x75AF6589202Dc4275fa56bC57eC77cE8Ce81BD64": {
      "balance": "0x900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

and have run `geth --datadir node1/ init genesis.json` to initialise with the genesis block. Then after creating and making the boot node up, I am trying to make my node up using

```
`nohup geth --datadir node1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30303 --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 3503 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' --bootnodes'enode://00f1bd4f26b16a7216a46de5324aac8b33ec3fbc3de4987c06dfa7549511210b9745961e2664b46cc63eafbfff37fd0b135080766ba5efde28c33131e0c13c9
8@127.0.0.1:30302' --networkid 1505 --gasprice '1' --unlock 0 --password node1/password.txt --mine > node1/01.log 2>&1 &`
```

where "*00f1bd4f26b16a7216a46de5324aac8b33ec3fbc3de4987c06dfa7549511210b9745961e2664b46cc63eafbfff37fd0b135080766ba5efde28c33131e0c13c9
8*" is my boot node address.

I am using **go-ethereum v1.9.1-stable-b7b2f60f**.

The error logs of making the node up is [image]

I have checked with older version of geth v1.8.27 the problem cannot be reproducible, so is it the version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clique needs the initial list of signers in the extra-data section. Please use `puppeth` to generate a valid Clique genesis block. You don't need to manage your network with Puppeth afterwards, you can also just create the genesis and dump it out.

Comment: It is always advisable to use puppeth to generate genesis.json file if one is using PoA for creating the private blockchain